# Is there a logical-or-type operator in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, logical-or

I have an angular service where I want to expose an observable which acts as logical 'or' of sorts. Say I have multiple source sequences which can give `on` and `off` values. I need to output `true` any time anything is `on`, and go back to `false` when all values are `off`.

Example:

```
const replaceInput = input => input === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on';
const getSource = (name) => Observable.interval(1000)
    .scan(
        input => Math.random() > 0.5 ? replaceInput(input) : input,
        'off' // initial value
    )
    .do(val => console.log(`${name}: ${val});

const first$ = getSource('first');
const second$ = getSource('second');
const result$ = ???;
```

Now, I've tried with `result$ = Observable.merge(first$, second$)`, but that gives always `on`. I have also tried with `result$ = combineLatest(first$, second$)`, so that is somewhat ok, but my inputs are out of sync, so it's not always perfect. I mean, first$ may emit more than one value while second may never fire and the other way around. What else can I do?

I've thought of some mergeMap or similar, and then keeping the state on the outside context, that way I run updates on any event. But then I get into a problem, an 'off' event might mean 'off', but only if other sequences are also 'off', so it gets tricky quickly.

Comment: You can use filter operator and emit only when value matches according to your requirement,

Comment: So what would that look like?

Comment: looks to me in your code, once input is 'on' there's no logic to set it back to off

Comment: @FanCheung exactly, how would I achieve that? I've edited my question to clarify what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually gave the answer basically yourself:

```
const result$ = Observable.combineLatest(first$, second$)
  .map(values => values.some(value => value === 'on'));
```

> so that is somewhat ok, but my inputs are out of sync, so it's not always perfect.

I don't understand what you mean, to be honest. You stated clearly in your question that you want this:

> I need to output true any time anything is on.

So if the inputs change with some time delay in between, you will have an intermediate result state. That's perfectly consistent with your question.

If you want to somehow wait for all inputs to change because they might change around the same time, you can add a `debounceTime` to it:

```
const result$ = Observable.combineLatest(first$, second$)
  .debounceTime(100)
  .map(values => values.some(value => value === 'on'));
```

Or if you want to suppress the `false` emissions, just filter them:

```
const result$ = Observable.combineLatest(first$, second$)
  .map(values => values.some(value => value === 'on'))
  .filter(Boolean); // sneaky trick; you can also use "value => value"
```

You can of course combine both.

Comment: But doesn't combineLatest emit an array of two values?

Comment: And observable.merge gives 'on' on the first true event, and then stays 'on' forever.

Comment: Oh, but I also need to switch back to 'false'. That was missing in my answer.

Comment: I use `combineLatest` to get both values and then `map` to determine the actual result. I don't see how `merge` would answer this question at all, it doesn't fulfill the actual requirement.

Comment: I get that. I am just saying that with combineLatest I am sometimes stuck as first$ and second$ aren't in sync - that is, one may emit multiple events, while the other may emit none at all, or one, or more.

Comment: An input emitting multiple times is not an issue, that's what all of this is for. If you want to ensure each input has a starting value, use `first$.startWith('off')` in the `combineLatest`.

Comment: … apart from that, `combineLatest` will emit whenever *any* input observable emits, as long as all of them have emitted at least once. So using `startWith` this changes to »will emit anytime any input changes«, which seems to me is what you want.

Comment: Ok. I was under the impression, that combineLatest will wait for an event from both before it itself emits a value. What you describe is actually what I need.

Comment: Nope, see the summary of `combineLatest` in the docs: »When any observable emits a value, emit the latest value from each.« :-)

Answer (score 2):

see if this is what you look for

```
let randomInput=()=>Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
.map(()=>Math.random()>0.5?'on':'off')
.startWith('off')
.map(value=>value==='on'?true:false)

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(randomInput(),randomInput())
.map(([first,second])=>first||second).subscribe(console.log)
```